# Precompute and store Tensorflow Graphs for loss function

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function

I am working on a sequence to sequence TensorFlow program that uses RNNs to predict tensors of size `(BATCH_SIZE x L x 11)`. I have a loss function which takes the `(BATCH_SIZE x L x 11)` tensor and transforms this into another tensor representing 3D coordinates which has size `(BATCH_SIZE x L' x 3)` where `L'` is a function of `L`.

Unfortunately, when I implemented this loss function to operate on the latter tensor (`L'`), my training time sky-rocketed from 9hrs / epoch to 300 hrs/epoch. I believe the problem lies in the creation of each computation graph for every batch - this makes everything extremely slow.

Is there some way I can precompute part of my computation graph to save time? Both the building and the differentiating seem to take forever. (Note that this part of the graph only exits in the loss function, and does not need to be trained since I have a mathematical mapping from `L` space to `L'` space).

Thank you very much. I would appreciate any advice about how to load prebuilt subgraphs in TF or if there are better alternatives (i.e. moving to a backend like PyTorch that supports dynamic batch shapes).

Comment: What do you mean L' depends on L ? The graph should only be built at initialization. You might want to pad your samples to the biggest (L,L') possible. The network will handle it.

Comment: The model predicts a tensor T1 of shape `(BATCH_SIZE x L x 11)`. The loss function takes tensor T1 and then, by applying a transformation produces a set of coordinates T2 of shape `(BATCH_SIZE x L' x 3)` where `L'` = `(3L + b)`. I don't think the graph of T2 is made until runtime because each batch is a different size and I am using TensorArrays to account for this dynamically. 

It's true that I can attempt to pad samples to all equal sizes but this may dramatically increase the memory requirement of the program. Thanks so much for your feedback.

Comment: You don't actually have to save it padded. Just make an input_fn which pads the input at runtime. What's usually done for variable length sequences (e.g. text sequences), is to build different graphs, say for length =5,10,15,30, and pad the data to the graph with closest and superior length. I am pretty sure making the graph at runtime is a huge waste of time and resources.

Comment: I see. My program already reads in batches and pads the input at runtime. However, I would definitely like to learn how to build graphs of different lengths and then choose which one to use based on the batch length, as you mentioned. Can you point me in the right direction? That is exactly what I had in mind when I posted this question, but I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: [This](https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/) is an example on how to classify sequences of variable length. I believe they only use one graph, One way to solve your problem is probably to consider their solution, and just create different graphs (say 2), for different possible lengths. Feed (both for train and predict) to the correct graph with a simple if statement.

Comment: You're correct, they do not use more than one graph. Do you imagine using python control expressions to select which graph to use for each batch? Or do you imagine this being done using tf.cond() and conditional graphs?

Comment: The simplest way would be to build different graphs, for differents sizes. you then split the dataset according to those lengths, and if you need to predict a certain sequence, then you feed it into the corresponding graph.